# Unique ou algo similar para 3 ou mais tabelas diferentes

Tags: sql, erp

Senhores,

Na empresa onde eu trabalho utiliza um ERP que não sei por qual motivo, é realizado a digitação de notas de vendas, devolução de vendas e devoluções de compras em três formulários distintos, sendo que a mesma atividade poderia ser realizada no mesmo formulário, enfim, o campo de nf numero, é igual para a os três formulários e não pode ser repetido, se no formulário de venda utilizou o nf numero 525, a próxima digitação será o 526 em qualquer um dos três formulários, para isso a empresa do ERP utilizou uma função que trás o ultimo numero utilizado, acrescenta + 1 e acha o próximo a ser utilizado. Quem tem um pouco de conhecimento, entenderá que isso é uma baita gambiarra e que em algum momento um dos três formulários poderá pegar o mesmo numero, caso a digitação ocorra ao mesmo tempo. Agora, como contornar essa situação? Já entrei em contato com a empresa faz uns 3 meses referente a esse problema, varias cobranças e ainda tenho o problema aqui na empresa.

Função utilizada:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[NfNumero]

(
    @NfEspecie VARCHAR(3),
    @NfSerie VARCHAR(3)
)

RETURNS NUMERIC(15)

AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @NfNumero AS NUMERIC(15)

SELECT @NfNumero = MAX(A.NfNumero)
  FROM ( 

  SELECT ISNULL(MAX(NfNumero),0) AS NfNumero 
    FROM Venda WITH(NOLOCK)
   WHERE NfEspecie  = @NfEspecie
     AND NfSerie   = @NfSerie

   UNION ALL

  SELECT ISNULL(MAX(NfNumero),0) NfNumero 
    FROM DevolucoesVendas  WITH(NOLOCK)
   WHERE NfEspecie = @NfEspecie
     AND NfSerie   = @NfSerie

   UNION ALL

  SELECT ISNULL(MAX(NfNumero),0) NfNumero  
    FROM DevolucoesCompras WITH(NOLOCK)
   WHERE NfEspecie = @NfEspecie 
     AND Empresa   = @Empresa 
     AND NfSerie   = @NfSerie   ) AS A

RETURN @NfNumero + 1

END
```

Comment: O problema já ocorreu ? É preciso ver as três (ao menos) chamadas para ver se estão corretas (sem entrar em detalhes) , quando se compra um ERP e porque não se quer preocupar com estas coisas...

Comment: A chamada é simples, quando a nota "nasce", o campo de numero é 0 (zero), no momento em que é gravado o registro,  é feito um update pegando o retorno dessa função e salvando no campo de nf numero. Nos três formulários é da mesma forma.

Comment: Ok , se não tem um lock e transactions pode mesmo ter problema , mas você é cliente deste erp ? Pode alterar o código ? Já teve chave duplicada ? Sua briga é com o fornecedor.

Comment: Sim, consigo alterar alguns trechos que utilize SQL Server, como functions e procedures, além de algumas consultas. Já a questão do fornecedor, é outra história que melhor não entrar em detalhes, por que é decepcionante.

Comment: Sei o que é isto , já pensou numa trigger de validação , iria garantir a unicidade , veja se não viola o contrato.

Comment: Já pensei em trigger sim, mas como ultima alternativa.

Comment: ... mas , o problema já ocorreu ?!

Comment: Sim, ocorre toda semana, pelo menos uns 15 casos, depende do fluxo de notas geradas simultaneamente.

Comment: Talvez (não conheço sql server a fundo) não usando o WITH(NOLOCK), o perigo seria ter travamentos http://sqlserverplanet.com/tsql/using-with-nolock
http://sqlserverplanet.com/optimization/set-transaction-isolation-level mas tipo da coisa que quem compra um erp não deveria ser preocupar ...